# How to actually center (vertical and horizontal) text inside a nested div

Tags: html, css

I Know there are several questions about this topic, however I think they *depend* a bit on another `CSS properties` given before.

I have a nested `<div id="tituloParametros>"` and I need its text/contain to be centred on vertical and horizontal position.

This is my markup:

```
<div id="outer">

        <div id="parametros">
        <div id="tituloParametros">Ingresa los puntos conocidos x,f(x)</div>
        </div>

        <div id="resultados">
            <div id="graficos">
                <div id="bars"></div>
                <div id="fx"></div>
                <div id="pinchetabla">Tabla inútil</div>
            </div>
            <div id="loquerealmenteimporta"></div>  
        </div>

</div>
```

And this is the applied CSS:

```
#outer{

  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  width: 1350px; 
  height: 640px;
}

#parametros {
  float:left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}
      #tituloParametros {
        height: 9%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle
      }

#resultados {
  float:right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}

      #graficos {
        height: 75%;
        width: 100%;
      }

          #bars {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            width: 30%;
          }

          #fx {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            width: 30%;
          }          

          #pinchetabla {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            width: 40%;
          }

      #loquerealmenteimporta {
        height: 25%;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

I thought that:

```
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle
```

both will make it but it didn't. Adding `display: table-cell;` doesn't solve it neither, it actually crops the background to the text limits.

This is [how it looks like](http://jsfiddle.net/U2y8L/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - the `table`/`table-cell` approach doesn't work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wwx2A/).

As an alternative, you could resort to the absolute positioning method. An element will be vertically centered when the `top` value is `50%` subtracted by half the element's height. In this instance, it shouldn't be a problem because the height is already set with the `%` unit. `100%` - `50%` - `9%`*`.5` = `45.5%` If this weren't the case, you could use `calc()` or negative margins to subtract the `px` unit from the `%` unit. In this case, it's worth noting that the child element is absolutely positioned *relative* to the parent element.

Updated CSS -- [**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/P2dvB/)

```
#parametros {
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    outline : 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}
#tituloParametros {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9%;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:45.5%
}
```

The element `#tituloParametros` is now centered within the parent element. If you want to center the text within it, you could wrap the text with a span element and then use the `table`/`table-cell` vertical centering approach:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfz7Y/)

```
#tituloParametros {
   /* other styling.. */
    display:table;
}
#tituloParametros > span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Oh! Well, I only want the text centred within its down div, not such div centred at its outer  :)

Comment: @diegoaguilar I guess I misunderstood! You can just use that second part then. Here is an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfz7Y/1/) It's better than the `line-height` solution because it will work with a dynamic height..

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful. Btw which software for linux (and not Dreamweaver or similars) would help at designing more complicated layouts would you recomend?

Comment: @diegoaguilar I wouldn't really be able to answer that. I have done all my development with the default windows notepad and the Google Chrome developer tool. Sublime text is a nice editor if you want syntax highlighting.. it's good for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my fix for this!::::
HTML:

```
<div id="parametros">
<div id="tituloParametros"><p>Ingresa los puntos conocidos x,f(x)</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #tituloParametros {
            height: 70px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:middle
          }
          #tituloParametros p{
            line-height: 70px;
          }
```

Comment: What if I always use percents for `divs` `height` and `width`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Universal vertical center with CSS</title>
  <style>
    .greenBorder {border: 1px solid green;} /* just borders to see it */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="greenBorder" style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
        any text<br>
        any height<br>
        any content, for example generated from DB<br>
        everything is vertically centered
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the demo
http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-align-final-solution-en.html